# Angular 8 routerLink doesn't work properly

Tags: angular-ui-router

it's my first time on the forum,

I started a new app with Angular 8 and I have a problem with routerLink.

In fact, I registered properly (I think) the routes with the path and component associated. When you click on the product-link, you are directed on the details-component.

The problem is when I click on the link, my component appears on the same page and not on the page apart.

Could you please help me find out what is wrong?

Here is registering routes in app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: ProductDisplayComponent},
  {path: 'products/:productId', component: ProductDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'cart', component: CartComponent},
];
```

This is my detail-component.ts :

```
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  product;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }
```

This is routetrLink directive in product-display.component.html :

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; index as productId">
  <h3>
    <a [title]="product.name + ' details'" [routerLink]="['/products', productId]">
      {{product.name}}
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```